# Куда схлопывается абзац?

Tags: html, css

Господа просто преглупейший вопрос, но я зашёл в тупик....

Куда девается абзац?

http://jsfiddle.net/aKakt/1/

HTML:

```
<p>
     <h1>Ошибка 404</h1>
     <h2>Страница не доступна</h2>
</p>

<div>
    <h1>Ошибка 404</h1>
    <h2>Страница не доступна</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p, div {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем здесь:

[MDN `<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

> Permitted content **[Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)**.

в ссылке написано:

> Elements belonging to this category are
>
> `<abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>`
>
> and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).

A few other elements belong to this category, but only if a specific condition is fulfilled:

```
<a>, if it contains only phrasing content
<area>, if it is a descendant of a <map> element
<del>, if it contains only phrasing content
<ins>, if it contains only phrasing content
<link>, if the itemprop attribute is present
<map>, if it contains only phrasing content
<meta>, if the itemprop attribute is present
```

говоря по русски, внутри `<p>` могут быть только элементы из первого списка, и элементы из второго с ограничениями:

1. `<a><del><ins><link><map>` - могут содержать только элементы первого списка, либо рекурсивно удовлетворяющее этим трем условиям
2. `<area>` только в случае если она внутри `map`
3. `<meta>` только если есть атрибут `itemprop`

надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: да спасибо все очень доступно, только интересно в чем логика этих ограничений? скажем понятно глупо блочные элементы помещать внутрь строчных, но тут P это как блок?

Comment: стандартом html это объясняется, мне влом искать строчку в стандарте это описывающую. А если вам правда интересны причины такого стандарта, покрутитесь на рассылках w3c (не w3school, а именно на w3c) и если не найдете объяснения спросите. (моя ставка - так проще парсить/рендерить ведь не всегда такие монстры в комнату помещались какие сечас в карманах у людей)

Comment: Раз уж такие дела, частенько применяю:

    CSS:
    a { display: inline-block; }
    a img { display: block; }
    
    HTML:
    <a href="anylink.html">
       <img src="anypic.png" alt="picture" />
    </a>

Как вы считаете, корректны ли такие конструкции?

Comment: думаю да. `<a>` должна содержать только Phrasing content. , `<img>` - Phrasing content.